# overflow scroll hide scroll when text doesnt overflow

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide the scroll bar when the text inside it doesn't overflow the height of the container. i want to make the scroll bar visible when the text overflows or exceed the height.

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    sample text
</div>
```

SAMPLE JS: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly58w9ts/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:scroll` http://jsfiddle.net/Ly58w9ts/2/

Comment: @MichaelPon yeah i forgot that